# Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id when reverting a flow in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: git, pipelines, cicd

I'm super new to development workflow using Git and Visual Studio Code. In our company, the deployment of code and configurations are done via Azure Dev Ops CI/CD pipeline. When I deployed a new flow, everything went successfully. But when I try to revert my change (essentially, rollback to delete the flow), the revert feature branch fails to validate and I get the error 'insufficient access rights on cross-reference id'. The user account used in the pipeline has system admin profile so it doesn't seem access related. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a flow using automated CI/CD has always been tricky, here is a [fairly detailed documentation](https://gearset.com/blog/flows-and-flow-definitions) for the possible cause.

I would recommend you remove the flow you want to revert from your version control and manually deactivate and delete the flow from the target org.

Comment: Thank you Anmol! I reviewed the link you recommended but am still unclear as to why. All I see in the article is 'Cause: This error is fairly general-purpose with a variety of possible causes, but in the instance we’re interested in it’s triggered by the deletion of a flow definition.' Surprisingly I don't run into the same issue when I deploy a version of an existing process builder. I'm able to successfully revert it via pipeline. Not sure if the roll back issue is isolated to the brand new flows only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Salesforce known issue for this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002KI7bQAG

I hope flow deletion becomes much easier once this is resolved. Please mark this KI as "This issue affects me" to raise the awareness with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing the same error when trying to delete a Flow (version) via the UI, VSCode/CLI or a destructive Change Set:
check whether any instances of the Flow are listed under "Paused and Failed Flow Interviews" in Setup.

If there are, manually delete them, then try again to delete your Flow (version).